# log4j is configured to be web but there is no output

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, log4j, spring-4

I modified the log4j.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration PUBLIC "-//APACHE//DTD LOG4J 1.2//EN" "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration debug="true" xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

    <!-- Appenders -->
    <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="Target" value="System.out" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p: %c - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <!-- Application Loggers -->
    <logger name="com.ambre.hib">
        <level value="info" />
    </logger>

    <!-- 3rdparty Loggers -->
    <logger name="org.springframework.core">
        <level value="info" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.springframework.beans">
        <level value="info" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.springframework.context">
        <level value="info" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.springframework.web">
        <level value="DEBUG" />
    </logger>

    <!-- Root Logger -->
    <root>
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Then I deployed and run my app ; and I received an error on the browser : `The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect`.

I looked the IDE console but there is nothing on the console ! So where can I find the log ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anywhere. I would need more information on what is your application server and its configuration.

This error might even be something the application server finds before it can determine it is your webapp it should invoke.

I'd try to look in the application server logs or application server log configuration. For example, if it was a debian tomcat 8 it could be 
/var/log/tomcat8/catalina.out
and configuration in 
/etc/tomcat8/logging.properties

But if it is an application server launched from your IDE it might be in your IDE directory or somewhere. Try to look up the server configuration in your IDE if you don't know where your application server is.